# I'm trying connect my users to metamask Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: ethereum is not defined at connectMetamask at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js, decentralized-applications

how do i slve this error im trying connect my users to metamask index.html:38 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: ethereum is not defined at connectMetamask (index.html:38:30) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:25:41)

I tried watching tutorials and chat gpt still no help